# Whether to cap the dependent variable while treating the outliers?

Tags: r, regression, modeling, outliers, dependent-variable

So I am trying to run a linear regression model in **R** where the objective is to identify what's driving the credit card spends including both primary and secondary. I have a dataset with 10000 obs

I started with running a UDF checking for P99 etc statistics and observed that I have abnormally high maximum value for my dependent variables. Hence, I capped the variables which had outliers and now I just want to know should one also cap the dependent variable/s or leave it before performing variable reduction, etc.

Logically it doesn't seem right to cap the dependent variables.

Can anyone help me understand this better?

p.s UDF stands for User Defined Function and P99 Percentile 99. What I meant by that is I made the User Defined Functions in R to check outliers with the help of present methods like IQR but instead I have used percentiles etc